# How do I use more than 1 WHERE selects in my PHP query?

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I am trying to display all results from my database where the username is equal to the person that is logged in and where the search row isn't empty.

Here is the code that I thought up but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could do this?

```
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchresults WHERE user='{$_SESSION['user_name']}' WHERE search!='' ORDER BY date DESC") or die(mysql_error()); ?>
```

The issue I am having is that I don't know how to do more than one WHERE in the query.

Comment: Multiple `WHERE`. `WHERE user='{$_SESSION['user_name']}' AND search!=''`

Comment: And  use `IS NULL` for `empty and NULL` filed in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AND` here

```
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchresults 
      WHERE user='{$_SESSION['user_name']}' AND search!='' ORDER BY date DESC") or die(mysql_error()); ?>
```

Comment: Answer this as right answer, So this question marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Use AND keyword instead of the where. There is only one where clause is allowed in single query.

```
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchresults WHERE user='{$_SESSION['user_name']}' AND search!='' ORDER BY date DESC") or die(mysql_error()); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

```
<?php 
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchresults WHERE user='{$_SESSION['user_name']}' and search!='' ORDER BY date DESC") or die(mysql_error()); 
?>
```